# How to uninstall Cucumber in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, cucumber

OS: Windows7 64-bit

I have installed the followings for running Cucumber:

Ruby
Ruby Installer Development Kit
ANSICON
Bundler
Cucumber and RSpec

Lastly, I have verified the successful installation of Cucumber by running the command:

```
cucumber --help
```

I want to uninstall Cucumber. How can I do this?

Comment: `gem uninstall cucumber`

Comment: @ mudasobwa: Yes, this is working well. Please give answer instead of comment so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have cucumber installed as ruby gem, use the following to uninstall it:

```
gem uninstall cucumber
```